# How to handle Hadoop splits in case of large XML input file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have one really large input file which is an XML data.

So now when I put that in HDFS, logically the HDFS blocks will be created and the XML records will also be divided amongst blocks. Now the typical TextInputFormat handles the scenario by skipping the first line if it is not start of line and logically the previous mapper reads (over RPC) from this block till end of record.

In XML case how we can handle the scenario? I don't want to use the WholeFileInputFormat as that will not help me using the parallelism.

```
<books>
<book>
<author>Test</author>
<title>Hadoop Recipes</title>
<ISBN>04567GHFR</ISBN>
</book>
<book>
<author>Test</author>
<title>Hadoop Data</title>
<ISBN>04567ABCD</ISBN>
</book>
<book>
<author>Test1</author>
<title>C++</title>
<ISBN>FTYU9876</ISBN>
</book>
<book>
<author>Test1</author>
<title>Baby Tips</title>
<ISBN>ANBMKO09</ISBN>
</book>
</books>
```

The initialize function of the XMLRecordReader looks like -

```
public void initialize(InputSplit arg0, TaskAttemptContext arg1)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = arg1.getConfiguration();

        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) arg0;
        start = split.getStart();

        end = start + split.getLength();
        final Path file = split.getPath();
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
        fsin = fs.open(file);
        fsin.seek(start);

        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        try {
            db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = db.parse(fsin);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            BookWritable book = new BookWritable();
            NodeList author = element.getElementsByTagName("author");
            Element line = (Element) author.item(0);
            book.setBookAuthor(new Text(getCharacterDataFromElement(line)));

            NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
            line = (Element) title.item(0);
            book.setBookTitle(new Text(getCharacterDataFromElement(line)));

            NodeList isbn = element.getElementsByTagName("ISBN");
            line = (Element) isbn.item(0);
            book.setBookISBN(new Text(getCharacterDataFromElement(line)));

            mapBooks.put(Long.valueOf(i), book);
        }
        this.startPos = 0;
        endPos = mapBooks.size();
    }
```

Using the DOM parser for handling the XML parsing part, not sure but may be if I do a pattern match then the DOM parser parsing issue will be resolved (in case of broken XML in one of the splits) but will that also solve the last mapper completing the record from next input split?

Please correct me in case there is some fundamental issue and if any solution is there it will be a great help.

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: XML in HDFS is not that efficient, it proved to be more performant to convert XML to cvs or AVRO using a script or stand alone program and than upload it into HDFS. To convert about 25GB of XMLs might take a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well try out mahout's [XMLinputFormat](https://github.com/alexholmes/hadoop-book/blob/master/src/main/java/com/manning/hip/ch3/xml/XmlInputFormat.java) class. More explanation in the book 'Hadoop in action'

Comment: Ya, I have seen that code. My only doubt is even if I do a tag check and start reading the record correctly, will the last mapper pick the remaining record from next split. Ideally MR should not be leaving any records...

Comment: The lines -
if (!withinBlock && i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end) {
          return false;
        }
They just return false in case block boundary is hit thus leaving the XML record which is not complete. Cant we ensure that i goes to the next block in sequence to read lines till end tag is not met? If yes, what will be best approach to do the same?

Comment: I know its too late. But still wanted to clarify this. I looked into the code again, now for that if block even if it hits the block boundary withinBlock will always be true until if finds the end tag right, it is going to read the file till it hits end tag. Assume split 1 and split2 has a XMl split, now mapper 1 would produce the output for that XML split and mapper 2 will look for the next start tag and will proceed.In this case where is the chance of missing the records. Or anything wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an XML file could be splittable by itself. THen I don't think there is a generic public solution for you. The problem is there is not way to understand the tag hierarchy starting in the middle of the XML unless you know the structure of the XML a priori.

But your XML is very simple and you can create an Ad-Hoc splitter. As you have explained, the TextInputFormat skip the first characters until it reach the beginning of a new text line. Well, you can do the same thing looking for **book** tag instead a new line. Copy the code but instead to look for "\n" character look for the open tag for your items.

Be sure to use a SAX parser in your development, use DOM is not a good option to deal with big XML's. In a SAX parser you read one by one each tag and take an action in each event instead to load all the file in memory as in the case of DOM Tree generation.

Comment: Thanks Rojo for comment. I can skip the first few lines, thats not a problem. But my concern is, if I leave those lines in current split, will the previous mapper pick them automatically or do i need to handle this manually?

Comment: According with the comments in the code, the first record in all the splits is being ignored because it should be processed by the previous split, the exception is the first split. https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/LineRecordReader.java line 139.

Comment: But that only apply if you use standard LineRecordReader as TextInputFormat does. In you case, you can use it but instead to use the EbdOfLine as delimiter, you could be able to use the **book** tag as it. but that could end with invalid XML records (the start tag will be removed and in the first record and in the last the root element will be included). But you should be able to deal with that. To be honest, I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split the XML file first. There are Open Source XML splitters. Also at least two commercial split tools that claim to handle the XML structure automatically to ensure each split file is well-formed XML. Google "xml split tool" or "xml splitter"